# Inequality (related to Hölder's inequality?)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality

Is there any way to put the outer exponent inside the integral when the set we integrate over doesn't have finite measure? i.e.

$$\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx\right)^{\alpha}\leq C_{\alpha} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (g(x))^{\alpha}dx$$
for some function $g$. Here, $0<\alpha<1$.

I was thinking on splitting the function $f(x)$ into two functions and applying Hölder's inequality but it doesn't seem to work if $\alpha <1$. Am I right?

Any idea to get rid of $\alpha$?
Thanks!

Comment: How are $f$ and $g$ linked?

Comment: It doesn't matter, for example if $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ then it is OK to split $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}e^{-x^2/2}$ and apply Hölder so that one factor if finite $C_{\alpha}$. I mean $\left(\int e^{-x^2/2}e^{-x^2/2} dx \right)^{\alpha}\leq C_{\alpha,p} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-qx^2/2}dx\right)^{\alpha/q}$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

Comment: Then I could choose $q =\alpha$ and I would have got my wish, but here $0<\alpha<1$ so I can't apply Hölder's inequality with $q<1$ :( So I wonder if there is any other way to obtain an integral without a power outside.